# Layout and formatting without Dynamic Controls in WPF

Tags: wpf

How do I format and throw my controls in a layout in WPF? I mean, I know about making dynamic controls and throwing them on a Grid or a Panel or something, but is there a better way? Like if this were a web app, I could just use some HTML and CSS and get what I want but is there something better than creating dynamic controls in WPF? I have database table full of stuff which I want displayed in my WPF application. Can I modify the DataGrid or ListView or something else for this purpose? I'm attaching images, which might make it easier for you guys to understand what I'm talking about.

images:

my data, inside the database table - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHCv.png

my data, formatted with HTML and CSS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PHBH.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this in WPF is via [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

In general, if you want to display a set of data formatted as per your second screenshot, you'd bind the dataset (usually contained in a collection such as ObservableCollection) to a ListBox or similar child of ItemsControl, and set the `ItemsTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` you've created to display the items in the format you desire.

For example, a *very rough* approximation of your HTML layout:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="TypeOfYourDataObject">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Foreground="Turquoise" Text="{Binding NickName}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="11" Foreground="Gray" Text="email / "/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="11" Foreground="Turquoise" Text="{Binding EmailAddress}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock FontSize="11" Foreground="Gray" Text="web / "/>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="11" Foreground="Turquoise" Text="{Binding Url}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <Separator/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: By dynamic controls, I meant..

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Margin = new Thickness(10);
    label.Content = "Some value";

    someContainer.Children.Add(label);

Comment: Well, you'd certainly be better off defining your control in XAML, as I've demonstrated above. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

ps: I still haven't figured out how to post code, four spaces before every line doesn't work? :P

Comment: Hmm... 4 spaces before each line *should* work... Alternatively, I just use the button that appears above the editor (the one that looks like curly braces).

Comment: I guess you can't have code in comments, cause I wasn't having trouble with posting code in the main question/answer :)

Comment: You can highlight code by surrounding it with backticks, but you don't get any newlines or other whitespace-related formatting in comments, no.